# String too Large for DataOutputStream

Tags: android

I am trying to write a large String into my DataOutputStream however I am getting a `UTFDataFormatException` that says:

`String more than 65535 UTF bytes long`

This happens when I call:

`byteOut.writeUTF(stringArray.get(i));`

byteOut being my `DataOutputStream` and `stringArray.get(i);` being my string.

Is there anyway to get large string into this `DataOutputStream` or is there another solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem and here it is.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream byteOut = new DataOutputStream(baos);
byte[] data = stringArray.get(i).getBytes("UTF-8");
byteOut.write(data);
byteOut.close();
byte[] input = baos.toByteArray();
```

May not be, and probably isn't perfect but it works.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for creating the `OutputStream`? Take a look at this link: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290535/unable-to-write-into-dataoutputstream-beyond-a-specific-size-outofmemoryerror). Chances are the medium you're communicating over has constraints and you'll need to configure some parameters on the object.