# How to exclude devices with low RAM in Google Play Store?

Tags: android, low-memory, android-go

I would like to distribute my first Android app via the Google Play Store.

However, I want my app to be installed on devices with at least 512 MB of RAM since devices with low memory can crash the app.

It is impossible to find the RAM of each device and exclude them 1 by 1, there are like 3835 available devices that can run my app. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I searched around and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234221/specifying-android-market-ram-in-the-manifest) was the best I could find.  It isn't the best fix out there, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: I don't think that is possible as such, these are the filters available : http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html
Looks like you're gonna have to search for a workaround ...

Comment: Thanks AndrewSchuster and 2Dee for your efforts it looks like both of you are pointing to Filters but i don't think i can apply filters since i use third party tools to build Apk and not eclipse.Looks like i have to  take up lot of crash reviews.Let me know if there is any other way.

Comment: Or you could fix your app to run on devices with less RAM. There should be some middle ground between 'working great' and 'crashing the app'.

Comment: @ianhanniballake, my thoughts exactly ! Ram Kumar, you might want to reconsider the behavior of your app, I would definitely not see "take up lot of crash reviews" as a good way to handle this ...

Comment: @ianhanniballake and 2Dee Guys I did optimize well but the problem is I use HTML 5 game engine there is some problem with playing audio files in devices with low RAM it is the problem with game engine itself .So i couldn't do more.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I know this question is old, but still appearing on search results...

With the latest update from the Google Developer Console, now it's possible to exclude a device by RAM:

> 1. Sign in to your [Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/).
> 2. Select an app.
> 3. On the left menu, select **Device catalog**.
> 4. Select the "Excluded devices" tab.
> 5. Next to "Exclusion rules," select **Manage exclusion rules**.
> 6. Under "Exclude devices which match any of the following," select the drop-down.
> 7. Select RAM or System on Chip.
>
>    - To add multiple rules, select the **OR** button. Another selector will appear.
>    - To remove a rule, select the cancel icon.
>    - For more information on SafetyNet Exclusions, go to the [Android Developers site](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/index.html).
> 8. Review the device list that appears at the bottom of your screen.
> 9. Once your rule targets the right device list, save your changes.

Reference: [View & restrict your app's compatible devices](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455)

Comment: This is the right answer! But the instructions can get outdated quickly, so make sure to click on the reference link on the bottom of the answer