# Exclude low RAM devices in Android Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, low-memory, android-go

I would like to exclude in Android Manifest (not in Google Play Store) devices with low RAM memory.

Using:

```
uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.ram.normal" android:required="true"
```

excludes too many devices.

The best would be to exclude all devices which have the feature: "android.hardware.ram.low".

Pseudo code:

```
exclude-feature android:name="android.hardware.ram.low" android:excluded="true"
```

Comment: You can do that from Google Play Console at the time of Publishing app.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663188/how-to-exclude-devices-with-low-ram-in-google-play-store

Comment: Thanks. However I need to do it only in Android Manifest.

Comment: `android.hardware.ram.normal` is available starting from API 27. This means that using this feature will make your app unavailable for all devices below API 27 + all devices with API 27+ which don't have `android.hardware.ram.normal`. There is no other similar feature for this as I know.