# android:largeHeap="true" not working

Tags: android, resources, android-largeheap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [largeHeap=true manifest tag not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075276/largeheap-true-manifest-tag-not-working)

I put `android:largeHeap="true"` in the application tag of the manifest file and set the minSdk version to `android:minSdkVersion="12"` and `android:targetSdkVersion="15"`  but it does not work and I get the error message `"error: no resource identifier found for attribute 'large heap' in package 'android'`

How do I get it working?

Comment: That's funny, the linked answer which is supposedly a duplicate talks about the directive being accepted but not working, whereas this question talks about the directive not even being accepted.

Comment: and alas, I have a real answer to this question, but I cannot tell it to you because the question has been closed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075276/largeheap-true-manifest-tag-not-working)

also go through [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#largeHeap) of largeHeap attribute. It clearly states that *It only applies to the first application loaded into a process* and *if you're using a shared user ID to allow multiple applications to use a process, they all must use this option consistently or they will have unpredictable results.*

Comment: That answer says nothing about the case where the tag itself is being flagged as an error.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put android:largeHeap="true" in application tag in manifest file. Also check your project properties.

Comment: did you even read the question?!