# Android : byte allocation exceeds the byte maximum heap size

Tags: android, byte, out-of-memory, allocation

I'm working on an Android application which encrypt a media (picture, video, etc) using AES encryption and I have the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` when I read big files (e.g. more than 90 MB) :

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileToEncrypt));
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) fileToEncrypt.length());
bis.read(bb.array());
bis.close();
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275650/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-an-android-application) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075276/largeheap-true-manifest-tag-not-working) topics or others, I'm using the `android:largeHeap="true"` option in the AndroidManifest.xml, but I'm not sure that is the best solution. Is it ? If not, what is the best to manipulate big files ?

Comment: you should handle big files partially. `largeHeap` isn't consistent among android platforms. it won't give the same heap size on every phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android:largeHeap flag is potentially dangerous and I wouldn't recommend it to anyone. It's good when you want to try something, but you cannot rely on larger heap as final solution. Enabling large heap may result in unexpected crashes due to low physical memory, not only low dalvik memory for this specific application.

For me there are two solutions:

- Memory mapped files. There is a lot of stuff in the Internet about MMF. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html You can read a file block by block using some standard NIO classes. It creates an illusion that you have entire file in memory.
- Use native memory. See: http://code.google.com/p/native-buffer/ Using NDK you can access entire RAM. The problem is that you have to manage memory in C style.